# date conversion in Go

Tags: go

I have below code. Having date value as string type from request and trying to convert to time type. But, I have some issue with format.

```
type LeanData struct {
    Start_Date time.Time
}   
const dateLayout = "01-02-2006"

startdate := request.FormValue("startdate")
if len(strings.TrimSpace(startdate)) > 0 {
    sdate, err := time.Parse(dateLayout, startdate)
}
fmt.Println("startdate", startdate)
fmt.Println("sdate", sdate)
```

I have below output.

```
startdate 02-03-2016
sdate 2016-02-03 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

Here, I am doing conversion because start date is of type time.Time.
 I want to convert it as 2016-02-03 but not with 2016-02-03 00:00:00 +0000 UTC. 
Also, How to assign empty value to start date if value from request is nil/empty.

Can someone let me know how to achieve this?

Comment: It looks like the conversion is just fine. If you only want the date part without the time, use [`Time.Format()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) or [`Time.Date()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Date).

Answer (score 3):

`time.Parse` returns an object of type `time.Time` which contains date and time information. There is no type in Go only containing date information. You can however ignore the time part of the date when formatting it, eg:

```
fmt.Println("sdate", sdate.Format("2006-01-02"))
```

which will print:

```
sdate 2016-02-03
```

To initialize an empty time, just declare it as:

```
var sdate time.Time
```